# Why do some people confuse Shudras with untouchables?

Tags: caste-system, shudra, untouchability, varnashrama

In various questions in this platform, I have seen people classifying Shudras as untouchables whereas in reality, Shudras are a caste within the pale of the Varnâshrama system but untouchables(antyajas) are considered to be outside the pale of Varnâshrama. Then why this confusion persists ?

Comment: You are simply asking "why some users on this site are confused about some concept?". Well they have every right to be confused. Secondly, you have to at least present some proofs of posts where you've seen such "confusions". And, thirdly users can give wrong information in the question. The answer providers can correct that in their answers. They have that option.

Comment: @Rickcross, I just want to know why this confusion persists. As far as the facts are concerned, it is the antyajas who are denied temple entry, but here a significant number of people are speaking about Shudras(not antyajas)being banned from entering temples.

Comment: But that is for those individuals to answer who are confused. We others can only speculate which makes your question "opinion-based".

Comment: " but here a significant number of people are speaking on ban of Shudras(not antyajas) from entering temple" -- if that is your question then it can be answered.

Comment: Ok. It seems I will have to improve the questioning skills.

Comment: Technically no one is outside the Varnâshrama system, because it extends to people like apostates (who are not in the Chaturvarna). They are outside the Chaturvarna.

Answer (score 3):

You have to show some examples where you have seen the confusion for us to exactly understand your point.

Although Shudras and mixed castes (Antyajas - those who are born out forbidden marriages) are different, a Shudra's touch is also regarded as "sullying" just like an Antyaja's touch is.

> Manu Smriti 3.241. A boar makes (the rite) useless by inhaling the
> smell (of the offerings), a cock by the air of his wings, a dog by
> throwing his eye (on them), **a low-caste man by touching (them)**
>
> 5.104. Let him not allow a dead Brahmana to be carried out by a Sudra, while men of the same caste are at hand; **for that burnt-offering
> which is defiled by a Sudra’s touch is detrimental to (the deceased’s
> passage to) heaven.**

So, this might be the reason you are looking for.

Comment: Ok. Understood now.

Comment: Is touching only for Sudra and Dwijas or even Vaishyas Ksatriyas and Bramhanas can't touch themselves??

Comment: I mean I heard a Bramhana can't touch another Bramhana also.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru In which circumstances?

Comment: I really don't remember @Rickross

Answer (score 1):

I call it "misguided perception". The caste system was originally designed for social structure and division of responsibility, thought to be one of the efficient ways to run the society smoothly. Talking about the birth of each caste being sourced from different organs/body of the creator is, I consider, a pictorial representation of duties. It was never designed to create discrimination. Would you say torso is more important that head or vice versa?

But the way head rules your actions (pun intended), so did the few varnas thought their responsibilities are of higher importance, automatically leading to degradation of remaining varnas. Once we have discrimination, exploitation starts and hence we have concept like untouchables. Varna system no way supports ideas like untouchables but it is the flatted importance of few varnas to consider remaining varnas below them to the extent of considering them untouchables.

Terms like "untouchable" should be eradicated and as for the future of caste system, I would suggest you to read this - [Sadhguru on casts system](https://isha.sadhguru.org/us/en/wisdom/article/how-to-end-caste-system-india)